# Swapping two columns on two different rows in MySQL with primary key conflict

Tags: mysql, sql, join, swap

I am trying to swap two columns on two different rows (role).  I know I could do this by setting user variables, but I was trying to do it all in one query if possible.

My query is:

```
UPDATE table AS t1, table AS t2 
SET t1.role = 'standby', t2.role = 'primary'
WHERE t1.sysid = t2.sysid AND t1.role = 'primary' AND t2.role = 'standby';
```

The table structure is

```
sysid | role    | devid
1     | primary | dev1
1     | standby | dev2
```

Primary key is sysid,role

The problem seems to be the conflict between the primary keys at the time of the transaction, with error: `Error Code: 1706. Primary key/partition key update is not allowed since the table is updated both as 't1' and 't2'.`

Since MySQL processes left to right, I tried setting a temporary value to t1 first to avoid the conflict, but it still failed with the same error:

```
SET t1.role = 'tmp', t2.role = 'primary', t1.role = 'standby'
```

Is there a way to achieve this with MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a temporary value to swap the roles. Pick a value that doesn't exist yet to not cause key violation. Use transactions for data integrity.

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE table SET role = 'temprole' WHERE sysid = 1 and role = 'primary';
UPDATE table SET role = 'primary' WHERE sysid = 1 and role = 'standby';
UPDATE table SET role = 'standby' WHERE sysid = 1 and role = 'temprole';
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that might be the way to go.  I was trying to do it all in one query but it doesn't look like MySQL likes swapping the primary key in a self join.

Comment: The question is...does this need to be in a transaction?  I'm trying to think.  If one fails, it seems like they would all fail anyways.

Comment: Better to put it into transaction

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I gave you an upvote but I'm going to leave the question open to see if I can find a creative solution to a single query.

Comment: @Devon Thanks. There may be a more concise solution, let's see.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table AS t1 join table AS t2 on t1.sysid=t2.sysid
SET t1.role = if(t1.role = 'primary' AND t2.role = 'standby', 
                 'standby', 
                 if (t2.role = 'primary' AND t1.role = 'standby','primary',t1.role));
```

Join both tables and update one depending on conditions

UPDATE

I swapped columns but actually PK doesn't allow to execute the update. Should be set constraints check off before the call

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years since I've had to create a SQL statement manually, however is a flipflop possible?

```
UPDATE table SET role=IF(role='primary', 'secondary', 'primary') 
WHERE sysid = 1
ORDER BY role ASC;
```

Comment: I tried that in sqlfiddle, it doesn't work because there's a duplicate key conflict when it updates the first row. It doesn't do all the updates in parallel. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94f54

Comment: Yes, I just tried it.  Duplicate key entry.  That is a useful tool for non-PK fields though.

Comment: You could temporarily remove the index, do this swap, then add the index back.

Comment: Yes, that would be one method, however, I'd like this code to work for basic SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE privileges.